# If everything that I do gets represented statistically, then would my non biological version be considered real or artificial?

Tags: brain, cognitive

That is if my entire brain gets modeled both atom by atom and functionally in a virtual environment, then would my replica be considered artificial?

Comment: I think this is more a question for Philosophy.SE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can we say that machines are conscious?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10551/7001).